# How can I avoid an access denied exception when trying to access User Information?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have Metro style application in XAML/C# that shows the log on user information.  I used method "GetDisplayNameAsync（），GetPrincipalNameAsync（），GetDomainNameAsync（）"，but it can only show my display name, and throws exception "access is denied" when show principal and domain name.

How can I call GetPrincipalNameAsync and GetDomainNameAsync without getting an access denied exception?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the "Enterprise authentication" capability.  See [App capability declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx) for a little more info.

Comment: But i met another problem ，why i cannot get principal name and domain name now just use those two methods....they just return "".....can you give me a hand?

Comment: I have the same problem Heifeng - I have the Enterprise Auth capability enabled in the manifest, and yet I am still getting returned a blank string. If I reach a solution I will post it here.